# Relating different ways of writing the outer product.

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products, tensors, dual-spaces, outer-product

I am having a hard time seeing how a a few concepts relate to each other. I an specifically coming at this from the perspective of tensors.

If I take two regular vectors from $\Bbb R^2$:

$$u,v\in \Bbb R^2$$

And perform the outer product on them.

$$u\otimes v=\begin{pmatrix}u_1v_1 & u_1v_2 \\ u_2v_1 & u_2v_2\end{pmatrix}$$

This is to my understanding in tensor language the tensor product of two vectors. However, it also appears that this can also be written as the matrix product

$$uv^T=\begin{pmatrix}u_1v_1 & u_1v_2 \\ u_2v_1 & u_2v_2\end{pmatrix}$$

I understand notationally how these produce the same result, my problem is that (seemingly hand-wavingly) taking the tranpose of a vector changes it to a covector, which I understand belongs in the dual space but which I also thought constituted a totally different object. Is the relationship between a vector in V and what I might consider the "same vector but transposed" in V* allowed to be defined in this way:

$$v\in V, w\in V^*$$

$$v^T=w$$

It seems strange to me that two completely different objects from the perspective of tensors (i.e. a (0,1) and (1,0) tensor) are allowed to be interchanged like this.

Disclaimer: I am studying physics not mathematics so please have mercy on my abilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll help to first discuss *inner* products. Do we denote them $\langle u,\,v\rangle$ or $\langle u|v\rangle$? It's an important notational distinction. Let's start with the first one, which just requires a sesquilinear positive-definite map from vector pairs to scalars. Once we have this in place, we can define $\langle u|$ as the linear map from $|v\rangle$ to $\langle u,\,v\rangle$, then write this map's evaluation $\langle u,\,v\rangle$ at $|v\rangle$ as $\langle u|v\rangle$. Doing this, we note the set of linear maps considered here is a vector space, and we call it the dual space of the original one. So now we identify each "vanilla" vector with a specific function, and that function gets called a covector.

Now we can turn to outer products: just as $\langle u|$ is a linear map, $|u\rangle\langle v|$ is a symbol for a sesquilinear map from a covector $\langle a|$ and vector $|b\rangle$ to the scalar $\langle a,\,u\rangle\cdot\langle b,\,v\rangle$, where $\cdot$ denotes multiplication of scalars.

Comment: I have a few follow up questions if you don't mind. (1) What would be the difference between those two notations? (2) I understand that the vector and its dual have the same number of elements (in finite dimensional space), is it correct to say that every single scalar in the field over which the vector space is defined can be obtained by the inner product and also can can every vector in V be mapped to every scalar in F by some covector in V*?

Comment: Also if we define $\langle u|$ as a linear map from $|v\rangle$ to the scalar field can we define $|v\rangle$ as a linear map from $\langle u|$ to the scalar field? Does it work both ways? Because again referencing how I've seen tensors defined I want to think of the covectors as a function from V to F and *also* think of the vectors as a map from V* to F, is this the case?

Comment: @Charlie (1) $,$ lets us prove the existence of covectors implied in $|$. (2) If $v\ne0$, $u:=\frac{k}{\langle b,\,v\rangle}v\implies\langle u,\,v\rangle=k$. (3) The linear maps from covectors to scalars are of the form $\langle u|\mapsto\langle u,\,v\rangle$, so some $v$ specifies a map. We can thus identify such maps with relevant vectors.